# Different values of width returned in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to determine the screen's width and height to use them in a fragment. 
My fragment's layout has the id `background`.

If inside `onViewCreated` I use:

```
background = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.background);
        background.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int width = background.getMeasuredWidth();
                int height = background.getMeasuredHeight();
                Log.d("askj", width + "+" + height);
            }
        });
```

I get `1440+2276`

but if I use:

```
 WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    Log.d("askj", width + "+" + height);
```

or other related methods I get:

`1440+2560`

I'm using those parameters to set a background and I can clearly see that the whole screen size is not taken if I use the second approach. I don't really want to use that `Runnable()` so is there any way in which I can solve this ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    tools:context="com.example.home.background.HomeScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the layout file where the RelativeLayout with id `R.id.background` is defined.

Comment: I just updated with the layout

Comment: Why don't you just use the DisplayMetrics if it's what you want anyway?

Comment: If I use display metrics, even if I get those values when I actually draw my background color it shows only on 90% of the screen(width, the height is fine)

Comment: Wait, `match_parent` should always work. I thought you are interested in the actual values.

Comment: I am. I'm using them to create a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can *measure the background View* before your activity has added it to its view hierarchy by yourself using `measure` method.

```
background = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.background);
background.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
int backgroundHeight = background.getMeasuredHeight();
int backgroundWidth = background.getMeasuredWidth();
```

In my case I measured an inflated View but it had the width and height set to `match_paent`.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_field_text, null, false);
view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int viewHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: I'll try it now and get back to you :D

Comment: I got back  height - `16777215`  width - `16777215`

Comment: Do I have to convert them or something ? Why are they equal ?

Comment: No. `background.getMeasuredHeight()` should have returned the correct height in pixels. I also updated the answer with an example that returned the correct value in pixel. In my case I used `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`. Maybe `.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)` doesn't return the right value when used this way.

Comment: I changed it to match your edit and now I get 16777214 - 16777214

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewTreeObserver like Below:

```
background = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.background);

final ViewTreeObserver vto = background.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() { 
    //get View Width and height here 
    int width = background.getWidth();
    int height = background.getHeight();

    //Call anyfunction which uses width and height here
    function(width,height);

    //Then remove layoutChange Listener 
    ViewTreeObserver vto = background.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    } else { 
        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    } 
} 
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution to displayMetrics. If I want to go for something like this I can keep using `background.post` method